# Icon for internal search vs web (google) search

Tags: icons, search

I'm designing a book reader, where I need to search functions: Search inside the book, and search on Google.
How do I differentiate the icons without using Google's logo?

Comment: Hi Eyal. I'm afraid that as per our [FAQ] icon request questions are off topic for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including a "world" shape with the magnifying glass is commonly used for "Search the web" queries.

[image]

And then for the "inside search" the magnifying glass alone or maybe adding document or book shape along with it.

[image]